# SQL Server filter for weekend only in variable

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this variable of a string, which I can use to filter for certain days of the week, or the whole weekend using

```
where datepart(dw,date) in (@weekday)
```

where I declare `@weekday` as `nvarchar`

When I have `@weekday = '1'` or any single day it works perfectly but when I try `@weekday = '1,7'` it fails to convert the data type to `int`.

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Ideally, switch to a data type that is *designed* for holding multiple values, such as a table-valued parameter or xml. Rather than a string. But a quick search for `string split sql server` will find plenty of examples of working with a string, if you really want to.

Comment: Aaron Bertrand's series of articles, [Split strings the right way – or the next best way](http://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings), [Splitting Strings : A Follow-Up](http://sqlperformance.com/2012/08/t-sql-queries/splitting-strings-follow-up), and [Splitting Strings : Now with less T-SQL](http://sqlperformance.com/2012/08/t-sql-queries/splitting-strings-now-with-less-t-sql) provide, in my opinion, a definitive answer on this subject. In summary, use a table valued parameter if possible.

Comment: You should never use datepart(dw, date), it relys on local settings. Different values in "SET datefirst 1" will give different results

Comment: @t-clausen.dk *"You should never use datepart(dw, date)"* - What would you suggest instead then? In my opinion `DATEPART(DW, Date)` is perfectly valid (although I would prefer `DATEPART(WEEKDAY, date)`), as long as you specify `DATEFIRST`

Comment: @GarethD read my answer for a different solution than datefirst. When you use datepart. You need to set datefirst. Datefirst can't be set in a function. So you will have to include it every time you call that function

Comment: @GarethD if you look at all these answers and the question, noone has bothered to set DATEFIRST. So as you can see, it should be avoided because people tend to forget, giving different results on different systems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use this that way. You only have these options:

1. to run the whole script in a dynamic SQL statement, which would be bad.
2. change your where to something like that: `where datepart(dw,date) = @weekday1 OR datepart(dw,date) = @weekday2`
3. change your `nvarchar` variable to a table variable, insert 1 and 7 into it and using it in a `JOIN` inside your query to filter the rows.

Comment: another option is to use `xml`

Comment: Yes this could be used to. But I would suggest the table variable, as it should perform as the best in the end. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You are attempting to use `@weekday` as if you had a piece of dynamic SQL, such that your where clause would be:

```
where datepart(dw, date) in (1, 7)
```

However, what is actually happening is:

```
where datepart(dw, date) in ('1, 7')
```

This is trying to compare `datepart(dw, date)` to `'1, 7'` which is obviously doomed to fail because one is an `INT` and the other is an `NVARCHAR`.

Try either using dyanmic SQL or finding another solution to your problem.

You could for example try something like (may not work out the box but investigate it:

```
where (@weekday = '1, 7' AND datepart(dw,date) in (1, 7)) OR
      (@weekday != '1, 7' AND datepart(dw,date) = @weekday)
```

This sees if the `@weekday` is set to `'1, 7'`, and if so manually checks for a `datepart` in 1 and 7, or if not performs your original check for a normal weekday.

Answer (score 0):

You can write as:

```
DECLARE @xml as xml,@weekday as nvarchar(100),@delimiter as varchar(10)
SET @weekday='1,7'
SET @delimiter =','
SET @xml = cast(('<X>'+replace(@weekday,@delimiter ,'</X><X>')+'</X>') as xml)

(...)
where datepart(dw,date) in (
SELECT N.value('.', 'int') as value FROM @xml.nodes('X') as T(N)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this :

declare @weekday table (wday int)
insert into @weekday (wday) values (1)
insert into @weekday (wday) values (7)

where DATEPART(dw,f_ArriveDate) in (select * from @weekday)

Answer (score 0):

IN can only be used with a subselect or a list of values. Your @weekday is 1 value and will not be considered anymore than 1 value. When you compare a none numeric value with a numeric, you will get an error. Best way to solve this is to rewrite @weekday to a table. Here is an example how that can be done:

Considering 1 is monday, 2 tuesday... 7 sunday. This script will find the correct matching days

```
DECLARE  @weekday varchar(30)= '1,7'

DECLARE @t table(date date)
INSERT @t values
  ('2015-06-22'),('2015-06-23'),('2015-06-24'),('2015-06-25'),
  ('2015-06-26'),('2015-06-27'),('2015-06-28')

;WITH CTE as
(
  SELECT x - 1 x FROM 
    (values('1'),('2'),('3'),('4'),('5'),('6'),('7')) x(x)
  WHERE @weekday like '%' + x + '%'

)
SELECT date
FROM @t 
JOIN CTE
ON 
  datediff(d, 0, date)%7 = CTE.x
```